# Font-awesome Icons showing as squares on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, icons

I have been trying to solve this, I have zero experience with wordpress and the codex is confusing.

My apologies for lack of code, since I don't know what is necessary to link to provide insight for this question. I have been looking through this website and the answers I have found are not applicable to woocommerce.

this is the website in question: www.cazinco.com, i am still in the proccess of building it and this problem is holding me back.  As you can see none of the icons are displaying and they just show empty squares.

Does anyone know where this problem stems from and how to solve it?

Comment: I would suggest using Chrome's Developer Tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Using it we see in the console, the error: "Font from origin 'http://149.210.219.235' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.cazinco.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Your current set up is creating link hosted from http://149.210.219.235 when in fact they should be hosted from http://www.cazinco.com

Comment: Have you added FontAwesome font in your theme and set font-family to FontAwesome ??

Comment: Kdvy was right it was due to cross-origin issue. Thanks for the help